# Is it possible to derive a closed-form analytical expression when integrating over a triangular area of a bivariate Archimedean copula PDF?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

Let's use, for example, one of the simpler Archimedean copulas - the Clayton copula with $\theta>0$.

What I want to calculate is the probability associated with, say, a triangular region of dependent random variables, $v$ and $t$, as follows:

$$
\int_{t=m}^{t=n} \! \int_{v=g(t)=at+b}^{v=d} \! f_{V,T}(v,t) \, \mathrm{d}v \, \mathrm{d}t
$$

Where $g(t)$ is a linear function and $a,b,d,m,n$ are constants.  With copula PDF $c$,

$$
f_{V,T}(v,t) = f_V(v)f_T(t)c(F_V(v),F_T(t))
$$

I am using exponential distributions for the marginals, so the above integration is expressed as

$$
\int_m^n \! \int_{g(t)}^d \! \frac{\zeta e^{-\zeta v}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}(\theta+1)}{\left[\left(1-e^{-\zeta v}\right)\left(1-e^{-\lambda t}\right)\right]^{\theta+1}\left[\left(1-e^{-\zeta v}\right)^{-\theta}+\left(1-e^{-\lambda t}\right)^{-\theta}-1\right]^{2+\frac{1}{\theta}}} \, \mathrm{d}v \, \mathrm{d}t
$$

Now, can I find a closed-form analytical expression for the above? If so, what kind of integration strategies are involved here? If not, can it be demonstrated why a closed-form expression isn't possible?